# additional files for .aar file

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I am developing a number of web-services for Axis2 using Netbeans.

The problem is that the generated `.aar` file still requires some addition files (some simple `.txt` files and probably the `.jar` dependencies) to run.

I tried to copy them in `WEB-INF/services` folder but no luck.
Where should I put these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional files should be axis2 `bin` folder.